# Which column caused the insertion error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

The error is

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'b' to data type int.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]
(
    [columnA] varchar(50) NULL,
    [ColumnB] int NOT NULL,
    ColumnC int null
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1] ([columnA], [ColumnB], ColumnC)
VALUES (23, 56, 'b')
```

My ETL pipe line logs all error. Some are useful, such as

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ColumnB', table 'DWDev.dbo.Table_1', column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails'

whilst others are relatively useless.

How can I improve the usefulness of error message that I cannot directly action, such as that in the first sentence above?

Comment: The problem is, the first error can be generated in a *large* number of cases and in a lot of these, there may not even *be* a name to apply to the "destination" for the data. I.e. it can happen when evaluating subexpressions of a larger expression.

Comment: The only way you can give - "useful" - messages is to parse the data and test it's validity yourself. That however can require quite some work but then you can give exact messages. Otherwise, you're dependent on the system messages.

Answer (score 0):

For ColumnA DataType is Varchar(50), you need to decorate the value with single quotes And ColumnC Datatype is Int, you can't insert 'B', it should be an integer value.

The Order of Values you provided should be same as order of column specified in insert into Clause
 you can correct your query in 2 ways

```
           INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
           ([columnA]
           ,[ColumnB]
           ,ColumnC)
     VALUES
           ('23',
           56,
           1)
```

OR

```
           INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
           ([ColumnB]
           ,ColumnC,
            [columnA])
     VALUES
           (23,
           56,
           'b')
```

Comment: Yes Sahi, my example is contrived. I do not specific help with my code above.